# Images taking more time (4-5 min) to update in Android webview

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have converted my wordpress blog into app using Webview. But now i am facing serious issue of the time my android webview takes to update blog images on my app.

Whenever i change image in an existing blog, i have checked it on browser it takes nearly 2-3 seconds for updating the image. But my android webview shows me the old image for 4-5 minutes even after wordpress website is updated with new image.

I have tried clearing webview cache and also tried allowing dom storage, but it didn't helped me either. I have also used a refresh button to reload the page in webview, but still it shows me old image for 3-4 minutes.

So can anyone please help me to reduce this time issue that I am facing currently. I have added my code of the webview below

.Java file

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fantasy__football);
    this.setTitle("Football");

    F_foo = findViewById(R.id.fantasyf_Adview);
    AdRequest f_adRequest15 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    F_foo.loadAd(f_adRequest15);

    F_web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.fantasy_f_web);

    WebSettings webSettings = F_web.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    F_web.clearCache(true);
    F_web.loadUrl("muyrl.com");

    F_web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    F_web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            super.onPageFinished(view,url);
            view.clearCache(true);
        }
    });


    Button ref = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ref_fb);
    ref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            F_web.clearCache(true);
            F_web.reload();
        }
    });
```

.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fantasy_Football">


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/fantasy_f_web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</WebView>


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fantasyf_Adview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxx"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="369dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="446dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ref_fb"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Refresh"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So can anyone please help me with this issue or suggest me what i can do to update my images faster ?

Comment: Can you try to change user-agent and see if it has any effect?

Comment: hey, what you mean by user-agent ?

Comment: `webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36");` Try this and see if it changes anything..